# Dim screen on alert of div

Tags: html, css

I have the following html div and css when a pop up alert box fires. I want the rest of the screen around it to go dim, but the CSS isn't working.

Can we dim the screen around the focused div, using only css?

```css
.dim {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1 !important;
    background-color:black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;      /* khtml, old safari */
      -moz-opacity: 0.75;      /* mozilla, netscape */
           opacity: 0.75;      /* fx, safari, opera */
}
```

```html
<div class="dim" id="dialog" title="Event">
  <p>
      This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. 
      The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't understand your question exactly, but I think you're looking for a simple "lightbox"-effect.

You need two separate DIVs. The first one looks similiar to your CSS-Code above and overlays the normal website. The second DIV is for your message (or content). The trick is, that the z-index of the second div is higher than the z-index of the overlay-div.

**HTML:**

```html
<p>Normal Website content</p>
<p>Normal Website content</p>
<p>Normal Website content</p>
<p>Normal Website content</p>
<p>Normal Website content</p>
<p>Normal Website content</p>

<!-- The first DIV for creating an Overlay -->
<div class="dim"  title="Event">
</div>  

<!-- The second div. Note, that the wrapper is only need to center the real dialog div -->
<div class="dialog_wrapper">
    <div class="dialog">Dialog Window</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.dim {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:1 !important;
    background-color:black;
    filter: alpha(opacity=75); /* internet explorer */
    -khtml-opacity: 0.75;      /* khtml, old safari */
      -moz-opacity: 0.75;      /* mozilla, netscape */
           opacity: 0.75;      /* fx, safari, opera */
}
.dialog_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    display: block;
}
.dialog {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #333;
}
```

The Wrapper is only needed, if you want to align the dialog-div in the center of your screen.

#### [Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pqft/)

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate div for the background and change the z-index to -1.

```
<div class="dim"></div>
<div id="dialog" title="Event">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. 
  The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```